# Firebase PubSub Topic Quota Limit Exceed

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm getting "Topic quota exceeded" error on Firebase Logs Explorer but when I open Google Cloud console, I see no quota limit is exceeded. In fact, there's no google cloud API service that is used even 0.1% except one (which is 6.67%). Also, GCloud shows almost 0 invocations of a PubSub topic we're using but we've been using it for quite a long time to publish messages to its subscribers. I have no clue what's going on whatsoever. Any help regarding this matter would be highly appreciated.

[image: pubsub errors]
[image: Current Usage]
[image: No data in Topic Metrics]

Please note that there's only one pubsub topic being used in the app so far. So maximum number of topics per project is not the issue.

I've already checked the list of all the quotas against google cloud apis & services and none of them have been consumed even a little